# Проект Эйлера №50. Как суммировать числа из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ломаю голову и не могу решить задачу с Проекта Эйлера №50.
Какое из простых чисел меньше одного миллиона можно записать в виде суммы наибольшего количества последовательных простых чисел?

Написал функцию для реализации решета Эратосфена, что-бы были доступны простые числа в виде списка.
Но не могу сделать так что-бы например бралось первое число из списка и складывалось со вторым, если оно не равно 1млн, то оно складывается с третьим челом из списка, и т.д. (2+3(первые два простых числа) = 5 не = 1млн => 5+5(5 третье простое число) = 10 и т.д.)

```
def Sieve_Eratosphenus(limit):# Функция, реализующая решето Эратосфена
    prime = [True] * limit #список хранящий элементы от генератора
    for n in range(2, limit):#генератор (от 2 до 1000000)
        if prime[n]:
           yield n
           for i in range(n*n, limit, n): #перебирает все числа которые делятся на 2
               prime[i] = False

primes = list(Sieve_Eratosphenus(1000000))
```

Comment: А зачем вы сравниваете с миллионом? В задаче этого нет. И делайте не список из N true и false, а список, в котором содержаться простые числа [2,3,5,7,11...]. С ним намного проще работать.

Comment: Это просто набор простых чисел. Так как по задаче они нужны

Comment: А, ну точно. Так хитро делаете, что не разобрался.

Comment: Просто делаю как умею, навыка очень мало.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял условия задачи, то можно сделать так:

```
def Sieve_Eratosphenus(limit):# Функция, реализующая решето Эратосфена
    prime = [True] * limit #список хранящий элементы от генератора
    for n in range(2, limit):#генератор (от 2 до 1000000)
        if prime[n]:
           yield n
           for i in range(n*n, limit, n): #перебирает все числа которые делятся на 2
               prime[i] = False

limit = 1000000
primes = list(Sieve_Eratosphenus(limit)) # список простых чисел

res = 0
max_prime = 0 # максимальное простое число
for i in primes: # проходим по списку...
    res += i # прибавляем очередное простое число к результату
    if res < limit: # проверяем, что результат меньше предела
        if res in primes: # проверяем, что результат -- простое число
            max_prime = res 
    else:
        break


print(max_prime) # 958577
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение, но оно не верное, так как если посмотреть все числа которые выводятся при вашем подходе то будет 
2
5
5
17
17
41
41
41
41
41
41
197
197
.....
958577

Answer (score 0):

```
def Sieve_Eratosphenus(limit):# Функция, реализующая решето Эратосфена
prime = [True] * limit #список хранящий элементы от генератора
for n in range(2, limit):#генератор (от 2 до 1000000)
    if prime[n]:
       yield n
       for i in range(n*n, limit, n): #перебирает все числа которые деляться на 2
           prime[i] = False
limit = 1000000
primes = list(Sieve_Eratosphenus(limit))# Получаем все простые числа до 1 миллионов
print(primes)
count = 0
res = 0
for i in primes: # проходим по списку...
    count += 1
    res += i # прибавляем очередное простое число к результату
    if res < limit: # проверяем, что результат меньше предела
        print(count, res) # 546 997661 первое число номер сложения, второе результат
```

Думаю данная задача решается так, увы ответа на нее найти так и не смог...

Comment: Эта задача не решается за один for-цикл простым сложением всех чисел подряд. У вас тут вообще не та задача решается.  PS. комментарий про "которые делятся на 2" ведь неверный.

Comment: Почему не та задача решена?? вроде на поставленный вопрос ответ найден.
P.s. там идет увеличение на 2 пока выполняться условие

Comment: А он правильный?

Comment: Там идёт увеличение на n. 2 там только в самый первый раз.

Comment: Я не знаю, я не нашел ответы на проект.
Именно

Comment: В смысле не нашёл? Там под каждым вопросом поле для ввода ответа.  И почему вы тогда решили, что ответ найден, если правильный вам неизвестен? Про "именно" я не понял. n равно двум только в самый первый раз. А потом 3, 5 итд.

Comment: Спасибо, благодаря вам я понял как проверять. Не знал что на оригинальном сайте можно после регистрации посмотреть верен ли мой ответ.
ответ увы оказался не верным, а я уж обрадовался...
А при чем тут n если вы спрашивали про for i, в n записываются простые числа.
Простите меня за мою тупость, мне еще учиться и учиться..

Comment: Да не за что :) Я и думаю, что не может задача номер 50 так просто решаться. Я спрашивал про i, но ведь там шаг n. Вы же в решете Эратосфена каждое n-ое число удаляете.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю ваш вопрос. i служит для счетчика самого решета. Т.е. в это значения уходят числа которые нам по условию не подходят, не являются простыми, в i по очередной будет заноситься при n = 2: i=2,6,8,10,12,14,16,18 потом при n=3: i=6,9,12,15,18. И так далее. А оставшиеся числа и являются простыми.
Так я понимаю работу функции, так как я писал ее подсматривая в интернет.
Буду рад выслушать ваше мнение или советы

Comment: У вас в комментарии написано «перебирает все числа, которые делятся на 2».  Но ведь там перебираются все числа, которые делятся на n.

Comment: Просто так написано потому что первое число для перебора идет 2ка )))
Главное понять суть мне было )

Comment: Кстати, вам не зря в каждой задаче даны два-три примера. Это именно для того, чтобы проверить свой алгоритм.